# How to make button fit the form when resizing it (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, dock, shrink

This is testing form [image]

I want to make it adjustable for every size of form.

I set anchor property to `none` so that my button dont get resized itself.

I want to make something like constraint to right and bottom edge of the form in  android. So that on resizing form my button is placed in right position- 50px from bottom and 35px from right.

I tried with dock property , but when i set it to right, button gets height of form , thats not excatly what i want.

Does anybody know how to solve it? I hope u understood me...

**UPDATE**

As you didnt understood me let me clear this with image example. U saw the my original form with a size 1000x1000

When i resize it to 500x500 i want to look like this [image]
You can see button is in same position and form is changed, with the same size, but i cant achieve that in runtime , because when i resize the form , button disapears

Comment: Yeah I know how for sure, what code have YOU tried?

Comment: "I set anchor property to none so that my button don't get resized itself." So, you want to anchor the right and bottom edges - what do you think you SHOULD have set anchor to?

Comment: @DStanley i updated my question i hope its more clear now

Comment: @FloRida Setting anchor to Right, Bottom _should_ do that.

Comment: @DStanley yeah that should be all thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use anchor to Right, Bottom to make it adjustable when you resize the form.

[image]